# Insert into table with polymorphic association in database

Tags: mysql, insert, subtypes, polymorphic-associations

I want to design a database where some tables have multiple foreign keys.
I am looking for the best design approach.

I found out that this kind of problem is called "polymorphic association" in database. I found the Stack Overflow question [Foreign Key to multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844460/foreign-key-to-multiple-tables) and Nathan Skerl's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7844911) very helpful.

But according to the link above, if I want to insert a new user (not a new ticket, but a new user), what would be the insert statement based on the design?

First I insert into the `party`? How can I retrieve the id to insert into `user` or `group` table? Because it has identifying relationship with `user` and `group`.

---

Describe relationship for insert query:

```
    create table dbo.PartyType
(   
    PartyTypeId tinyint primary key,
    PartyTypeName varchar(10)
)

insert into dbo.PartyType
    values(1, 'User'), (2, 'Group');


create table dbo.Party
(
    PartyId int identity(1,1) primary key,
    PartyTypeId tinyint references dbo.PartyType(PartyTypeId),
    unique (PartyId, PartyTypeId)
)

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Group]
(
    ID int primary key,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PartyTypeId as cast(2 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (ID, PartyTypeId) references Party(PartyId, PartyTypeID)
)  

CREATE TABLE dbo.[User]
(
    ID int primary key,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    PartyTypeId as cast(1 as tinyint) persisted,
    foreign key (ID, PartyTypeId) references Party(PartyID, PartyTypeID)
)
```

It seems `user` has an identifying relationship with the `party` table: an existing child (user) depends on the existence of the party.
Now I want to insert a new user, for example when some user needs to sign up.

What would be the query to insert a new user?

Comment: `LAST_INSERT_ID()` maybe? What code do you have so far?

Comment: Forget about "polymorphic" and focus on whether "many:many" is 'right' for the relation.

Comment: @Charlieface : Its on the design, not in the code; I was asking on what is best practice to achieve multiple relation to one table that I visit the link I mention.
After that I was wondering ok, if the answer in the link is the right way, so how can I insert new users ? If some body want to sign up what would be the  right query and way to do that.

Comment: @RickJames : So you say the right way is to crate many:many relation to drive what I want, true?
And It would be confusing to deal with polymorphic association?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to represent as you haven't shown us. That particular article would normally refer to multiple 1:1 tables, not many:many tables. I can't tell you what database design you need if you have told us nothing about the relations between the different concepts in it. All I know is that you have `user`, `party`, `group` and a wild guess tells me that 1:1 is probably not right, it's probably 1:many. But you need to give us much more info.

Comment: @Charlieface : You are right, I have user, party, and group. Now a new user will sign up.
What would be insert query depending on the these entities?
I should insert into party table and then insert into user/groups?
Or if I insert into user table,  the party table will automatically fill? ( Cause it uses the primary key of that )

Comment: As I said, please [edit] your question and explain how these three entities relate to each other. Is a user in a party which is part of a group, or is a user part of a group which is in a party, or does a user exist independently of either etc? It's really unclear at the moment

Comment: It sounds like you want exactly 3 tables:  `user`, `party`, `group`.  If that is the case, please fabricate some data that shows a small example of data that might exist in those tables.

Comment: @Charlieface I also edited the question.
It seems User and party are different entity and has no relation; But identifying relationship with party table.

Comment: @RickJames : I did it.

Comment: I see. So you have the base table `party` and two child tables `user` and `group` (exclusive to each other, and therefore a polymorphic association). If you want to insert a new `user` you first need to insert a new `party` with `PartyTypeId=1`, then you need to insert a new `user` with the same `ID` and `PartyTypeId`

Comment: @Charlieface : So what would be the insert query? And how get the partyId and use that in user table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of a *polymorphic association*, where the primary key of a number of tables is the foreign key of a super-table.

You would first insert into the `Party` table, then take that inserted ID and insert that also into the `User` table:

```
insert into `Party` (PartyTypeId)
values (1);

insert into `User` (ID, Name)
values (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'SomeName');
```

Comment: So we should use las_insert_id function to get the last id.
Thank you so much